# How can I get the list of users who liked a tweets?

Tags: api, twitter

I use the twitter api, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-favorites-list, but it seems like I can only get one user's like tweets by username. How can I get the list of user who likes a tweets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Twitter does not provide an API for that.

The nearest you can get is seeing [who retweeted a status](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweeters-ids).